# unable to fetch the code from github to azure pipeline agent(self-hosted)

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" -c http.proxy="https://xxxxx:***@xxxxxxxxxxxx.local:8080/" -c http.sslVerify=false fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx': error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

### [warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 2.097 seconds before retry.

git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" -c http.proxy="https://xxxxxx:***@mproxy.xxxxxxxxxxxx.local:8080/" -c http.sslVerify=false fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/repo-name/branch/': error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

### [warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 3.099 seconds before retry.

git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" -c http.proxy="https://xxxxx:***@mproxy.xxxxxxxx.local:8080/" -c http.sslVerify=false fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/repo-name/branch/': error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

### [error]Git fetch failed with exit code: 128

Comment: Do you use Azure DevOps Service (on cloud) or Azure DevOps Server (on-premise)? How did you fetch code from github to azure pipeline agent machine, from command line or in Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `http://` instead of `https://` in `http.proxy="https://xxxxx:***@xxxxxxxxxxxx.local:8080/"`